# With which user does Oracle APEX create apps?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, privileges, oracle-apex-18.2

I'm trying to build an aplication on Oracle Apex 18.1 (DB 12.1)
I made a Workspace called "prueba01" provisioning an already existing schema: "OFERTAS".
[image: prueba01 workspace]

Now, when I try to make an app from "packaged apps", I get this error:
[image: prerequisite check failed error]

I'm logged in Apex as an Admin user
[image: admin account privileges]

And I already granted view privileges to APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER.
With which user does Apex create the app that I'm trying to build?

Comment: For further information on this, see the following appendix from the app builder user's guide https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/about-granted-privileges.htm

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, you should (connected to **database**, not Apex!) as a privileged user, such as `SYS`, run

```
grant create view to ofertas;
```